# Run JHipster in Docker with JHipster Registry-pass the variable ${jhipster.registry.password}

Tags: jhipster

I am running JHipster application in Docker with JHipster Registry
how to pass the variable ${jhipster.registry.password} to app.yml
May I ask how to pass the variable ${jhipster.registry.password} to app.yml?
            -

```
EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
```

Comment: it's probably an environment variable

Answer (score 2):

That value is parsed from your application's bootstrap.yml (or bootstrap-prod.yml in prod) found in `src/resources/config`.

Another way to set this variable is to set the JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD environment variable in your docker-compose app.yml file